# How to find the linear parameterization of a symbolic vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra

I have a symbolic vector y which I know contains linear expressions of the variables contained in a symbolic vector theta. Is there a way to compute the symbolic expression of A, where y = A * theta? I tried y*pinv(theta) but it doesn't seem to work.

Example:

```
syms a b real
theta = [a;b];
y = [2*a;2*b];
```

`y*pinv(theta)` gives

```
ans =   [ (2*a^2)/(a^2 + b^2), (2*a*b)/(a^2 + b^2)] 
        [ (2*a*b)/(a^2 + b^2), (2*b^2)/(a^2 + b^2)]
```

and

`y/theta` gives

```
ans =   [       2, 0]
        [ (2*b)/a, 0]
```

along with a warning that the solution is not unique.
I want to eradicate the symbolic variables from my result i.e. I want

```
ans =   [ 2, 0]
        [ 0, 2]
```

Comment: I think your columns are linearly dependent, i.e. your system does not have a unique solution, hence MATLAB throws you that error.

Comment: Of course it does not have a unique solution if seen as an equation! But the problem here can also be formulated as follows: Given a symbolic vector A which contains linear expressions of the variables a and b, can MATLAB compute the linear parameterization of A?

Comment: I assume `theta` is `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equationsToMatrix` function seems to be doing the job!
Try `equationsToMatrix(y,theta)`

Comment: You can also use `coeffs` on each element of `y`.